# Can we give Gauss's Lemma (polynomial) over the integers without the primitive condition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, polynomial-rings

I am currently reading Juliusz Brzezinski's book "Galois Theory Through Exercises", in which he states Gauss's Lemma as a useful test for the irreducibility of certain polynomials.

However, the statement of the lemma in the book is as follows:

> A nonconstant polynomial with integer coefficients is reducible in
> $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ if and only if it is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. More exactly, if $f ∈ \mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $f = gh$, where
> $g, h ∈ \mathbb{Q}[X]$, then there are rational numbers $r, s$ such that $rg, sh ∈ \mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $rs = 1$, so
> $f = (rg)(sh)$.

In the proof of the lemma the book states that

> Of course, if a polynomial $f ∈ \mathbb{Z}[X]$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, then it is reducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

But I must be missing something here, as this implication does not seem obvious to me. In fact, I would have thought that the implication doesn't always hold since the polynomial $f(X)=2X+2=2(X+1)$ is reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ (as neither $2$ nor $(X+1)$ are units in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$) but $f(X)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ because $2$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

I have seen Gauss's Lemma before, without incident, where it was stated with the condition that the polynomial must also be primitive, and I wonder if this is the source of my confusion.

Apologies if this is a stupid question, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If $f(X)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is primitive and reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, say, $f(X)=g(X)\,h(X)$ for some nonunit elements $g(X)$ and $h(X)$ of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, then $g(X)$ and $h(X)$ cannot be nonunit elements of $\mathbb{Z}$.  Therefore, $g(X)$ and $h(X)$ are nonunit elements of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Comment: @Batominovski what do you mean when you say $g(X), f(X)$ cannot be nonunit elements of $\mathbb{Z}$? If they cannot be nonunits of $\mathbb{Z}$ would this not mean they must be units of $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. equal to $\pm 1$?

Comment: That is not what I said.  What I tried to say is: if (for example) $g(X)$ is a constant (i.e., an element of $\mathbb{Z}$), then $g(X)$ has to be a unit element of $\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e., $g(X)=\pm 1$), otherwise $f(X)$ would not be a primitive polynomial.

Comment: @Batominovski Ah sorry I understand your comment now, thank you. This makes complete sense to me if we have the condition that $f(X)$ is a primitive, but in the book the primitive condition is not stated in the lemma, nor used in the proof anywhere that I can see. I was wondering what it is I am missing that allows the lemma to be stated and proved in this way.

Comment: If the book doesn't assume primitivity of $f$, then the statement is false.  I think the primitivity assumption is simply forgotten.

Comment: @Batominovski I suspected this might be the case. Thank you very much for your help.